# When can you use 'a same'?

Tags: articles

When will we use 'a same', instead of 'the same'? Is it grammatical to say:

1. We wore a same hat yesterday.
2. We talked to a same teacher everyday.

Comment: `a similar` or `the same` hat - definitely `the same teacher` so no it is not grammatical

Comment: If the hats really are the same, you can say "identical hats". But you can't say "identical teachers", at least, not unless they're clones.

Answer (score 5):

Hardly ever, and your two examples are ungrammatical. Just about the only way *same* can be preceded by *a* is in a phrase such as *a same day service*, where the indefinite article relates to *service*, and *same day* is adjectival.

Comment: One might even aver that _same day service_ could be hyphenated (i.e., _a same-day service_). (I'm not saying it needs to be, mind you, I'm just pointing out how unique such usages of "a same" happen to be.)